# Changing Password expiry date for limited users in Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, password, groups, password-policy

I have 50 users in my domain. But i have to set password expiry days for 90 for only 10 users. How can i do it. How can this be done without affecting any other users Password Policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fine-Grained Password Policies` feature allows to apply different restrictions for password and account lockout policies to different sets of users in a domain. What is important about Fine-grained password policies is that they are applied only to user objects and global security groups, but NOT to OUs.

You can create a separate security group, add required users and then apply PSO(password setting object) to this group.

[AD DS Fine-Grained Password and Account Lockout Policy Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770842(v=ws.10).aspx)